# How to used xml tags in svg file

Tags: xml, validation, google-chrome, svg, namespaces

I have a next svg code

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:mpc="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <mpc:signal pairid='8943'></mpc:signal>
     <text x='10' y='10'>12332</text>
 </svg>
```

But this code is not valid on http://validator.w3.org/.

What could be the problem?

Update code

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:mpc="http://www.crtc.com/mpclogic">
     <defs>
         <mpc:signal pairid='8943'></mpc:signal>
     </defs>
  <text x='10' y='10'>12332</text>
</svg>
```

But this code still returns next error - Line 6, Column 31: Element signal from namespace http://www.crtc.com/mpclogic not allowed as child of SVG element defs in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlns:mpc="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" says that you wish to use mpc as the prefix for the html namespace but `<signal>` is not an html tag. I suspect you want something other than http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml here.

Comment: <signal> - is it xml tag. Namespace for XML - [http://www.w3.org/1999/xml](http://www.w3.org/1999/xml) ?

Comment: There's no such thing as an XML namespace

Comment: Thank you very much. Than how i can used xml tags in svg?

Comment: Pick something other than a w3c defined namespace as your namespace. E.g. `"http://www.mycompany.com/mynamespace"`

Comment: I updated this code, but this code still returns error. Example code and error in post above. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Report it as a bug in the validator then.